# Every expression with [field] in an Access Report generates a #Name? error

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to create a basic report in MS Access but have run into an issue where I can't use references in expressions in the control source of a simple TextBox.

Access shows the following fields available for my view: ID, Status, DocNum. I want to check if the DocNum field is null and if not, manipulate the result.

I have a TextBox named docControl with the following as the Control Source:

```
= IIf(IsNull([docNum)]), "is empty", "is not")
```

This produces `#Name?` on the report. I also tried:

```
= [docNum]
```

And this also produces `#Name?` on the report. However, if I just select docNum from the Control Source dropdown, it displays the value just fine. I don't understand why `docNum` works and `=[docNum]` does not. Aren't they the same thing?

Any clarification is appreciated.

Comment: You show an extra parenthesis in expression - [docNum)].

Comment: Reports can be persnickety about referencing fields in expressions. I have seen them fail when field is not included on report. Bind a textbox directly to field (can hide the textbox) then do the calc in another textbox. Otherwise, do calc in query and bind textbox to that field.